# ScheduledExecutorService not getting triggered

Tags: java, java-8, scheduled-tasks

I am working with ScheduledExecutorService for the first time and have written a small program to test if it works following guidelines from [this](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/) article.

My code is using runnable as suggested in other posts on stack overflow.

```
public void ECSScheduler() {
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    Runnable task = () -> System.out.println("Scheduling: " + System.nanoTime());

    int initialDelay = 1;
    int period = 5;
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

I am trying to run it within a Spring application which is running on Jboss EAP 6.1 environment.

But the scheduler doesn't get triggered ever(neither after initialDelay nor period).

Do I need to call it from application after deploying ?? Or have I missed something here??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is pretty un-clear, are you sure that this methods gets called in the first place?

Comment: The code is working on my machine with IntelliJ 2017.2.6 and Java 8. Are you sure that the method is called?

Comment: Doing your own thread creation handling - and this you do when using a ScheduledExecutorService - is a no-go in an JEE application server. From JEE 7 on you can use `ManagedExecutorService`s, JBoss EAP 6 is JEE 6

Comment: Sorry, the issue was in my application listener from where the code was not getting called. Thanks @Eugene and for pointing that out.